# How to Convert Base64 to Char Array - C# - Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, microsoft-graph-api

My code receives a Base64 value as a String (Public String Base64Foto).
I must take this value and convert it to Char[] to send it to graph Microsoft.

```
private static async Task<bool> EnviarMicrosoft(DadosApData dadosApData)
    {
        try
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = "tenantID";
            var clientId = "clientID";
            var clientSecret = "clientSecret";
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };


            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dadosApData.Base64Foto);

            var charFromByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).ToCharArray();

            using var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charFromByte));

            await graphClient.Users[dadosApData.Email].Photo.Content.Request().PutAsync(stream);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LambdaLogger.Log(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

When I do this in Postman, it works normally (as a binary), but when I try to pass this to the code, it doesn't work, is my conversion wrong?

[image]

PS: I'm Receving the error: Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException

Comment: It seems like you're uploading a jpeg, which isn't textual data. Why do you want to convert it to a char array?

Comment: Your code is bizarre: you have bytes in `bytes`. Why do you converting it to a string, and then back to a byte array? Why do you not pass `bytes` to `MemoryStream`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Because I'm using the Microsoft Graph SDK and when I'm going to add the parameter, it says to put a char[]

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar how can i do this conversion to MemoryStream?

Comment: What says to put `char[]`? Please be more specific!

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Sorry, I explained it wrong, When I use the System.io.MemoryStream method with Encoding.utf8.GetBytes, converting my base64 image, at the time of sending I get an error of "Invalid Image"

However sending in postman the same image as Binary, it changes normally

Comment: So why do you not just do `using var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);`?

Comment: What you're doing at the moment is: 1) creating `byte[] bytes` by using `Convert.FromBase64String` 2) Pretending those bytes are UTF8-encoded text and converting that to a `string`, and then turning that into a `char[]`. 3) From there you convert that `char[]` into a `byte[]` again. 4) Using the resulting `byte[]` to construct a `MemoryStream`. The problem with all of this, is that UTF8 can't "round trip" arbitrary binary data ([example](https://rextester.com/LFJYO47226)). It loses information (i.e. corrupts the data). There's no reason not to construct the `MemoryStream` from `bytes`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I tested it here and it works now, thank you very much indeed!
You saved me too much!

Comment: What @DiplomacyNotWar said `There's no reason not to construct the MemoryStream from bytes` is very very very correct. Please allow me also put my test code below.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code and it can update the user photo:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task UploadAsync(IFormFile file) {
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    file.CopyTo(ms);
    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
    //string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "xx.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "client_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    var res = await graphClient.Users["user_id"].Photo.Content.Request().PutAsync(new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length));
}
```

cshtml:

```
<input id="picContent" type="file" name="photo" value="please upload a picture" />
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="upload"/>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            var formData = new FormData();
            var img = $("#picContent")[0].files[0];
            console.log(img);
            console.log($("#picContent").val());
            formData.append("file", img);
            $.ajax({
                data: formData,
                url:"https://localhost:44340/home/upload",
                type:"post",
                data:formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            })        
        })

    </script>
}
```